# Expression tree to initialize new anonymous object with arbitrary number of properties

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, anonymous-types

I'm trying to use LINQ expression trees to initialize a new anonymous object with a subset of fields from a passed-in object.  The subset of fields will typically be a single property but could be more (4 or so).

An example:

```
void DoWork(Type t)
{
    //do some work to figure out which properties I want to use
    List<PropertyInfo>() props = (from p in t.GetProperties()
                                    where p.HasAttribute(MyAttribute)
                                    select p).ToList();

    //now I want to create a lambda expression that's like:
    //  (x=> new {x.Prop1, x.Prop2, ...})
    //for each property in the list props

    //create parameter
    var param = Expression.Parameter(t,"t");
    //get list of expressions for properties
    var initValues = (from p in props
                        select Expression.PropertyOrField(param, p.Name)
                        ).ToList();

    //build expression body
    Expression body = Expression. //<<<< I have no idea what to do here

    //create lambda
    dynamic propLambda = Expression.Lambda(body, param);

    //use it!  MyFunction( x=> new {x.Prop1, x.Prop2,...});
    MyFunction(lambda);
}
```

Comment: Initializing an anonymous object is done using the constructor of the type.

Comment: So, the back question could be: How to create a new type based on a collection of properties extracted from a reflection query?

Comment: what is exactly your problem?

Comment: I don't think this can be done using only an expression tree. You'll need to build the type using something like `TypeBuilder` and then use `Expression.New` in your expression tree to construct an object from your newly-built type.

Comment: I agree, to do it you need to work with dynamically typebuilder. Perhaps you could create simple case from it. For example, something similar : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40933357/combining-multiple-expressions-to-dynamically-create-select-expression-containin/41364567#41364567

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bad news: Since you're gonna build the anonymous type dynamically at runtime, it doesn't exist at compile time, as it would if the compiler encountered a `new {...}` in your code. There's no way around `Reflection.Emit`, which isn't tivial.

The good news: I've already done it, because I had the same needs. Used ILDASM to see what the compiler generates and mimic that as closely as possible.

So without further ado:

```
/// <summary>
/// Creates types that are much like anonymous types.
/// </summary>
public static class TupleFactory
{
    // the dynamic module used to emit new types
    private static readonly ModuleBuilder _module = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName { Name = nameof(TupleFactory) }, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run).DefineDynamicModule(nameof(TupleFactory), false);

    // the generic type definitions constructed so far
    private static readonly Dictionary<ICollection<string>, Type> _genericTypeDefinitions = new Dictionary<ICollection<string>, Type>(CollectionComparer<string>.Default);

    // the new expression factory singletons constructed so far
    private static readonly Dictionary<ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, Type>>, ITupleFactory> _newExpressionFactories = new Dictionary<ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, Type>>, ITupleFactory>(new CollectionComparer<KeyValuePair<string, Type>>(KeyValueComparer<string, Type>.Default));

    // some reflection objects used
    private static readonly ConstructorInfo _objectCtor = typeof(object).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
    private static readonly MethodInfo _objectEquals = typeof(object).GetMethod("Equals", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance, null, new[] { typeof(object) }, null);
    private static readonly MethodInfo _objectGetHashCode = typeof(object).GetMethod("GetHashCode", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance, null, Type.EmptyTypes, null);
    private static readonly MethodInfo _objectToString = typeof(object).GetMethod("ToString", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance, null, Type.EmptyTypes, null);
    private static readonly MethodInfo _stringFormat = typeof(string).GetMethod("Format", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static, null, new[] { typeof(string), typeof(object[]) }, null);
    private static readonly MethodInfo _equalityComparerDefaultGetter;
    private static readonly MethodInfo _equalityComparerEquals;
    private static readonly MethodInfo _equalityComparerGetHashCode;

    static TupleFactory()
    {
        // init more reflection objects
        _equalityComparerDefaultGetter = typeof(EqualityComparer<>).GetProperty("Default", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static).GetGetMethod();
        var eqT = typeof(EqualityComparer<>).GetGenericArguments()[0];
        _equalityComparerEquals = typeof(EqualityComparer<>).GetMethod("Equals", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance, null, new[] { eqT, eqT }, null);
        _equalityComparerGetHashCode = typeof(EqualityComparer<>).GetMethod("GetHashCode", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance, null, new[] { eqT }, null);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a <see cref="ITupleFactory"/> singleton for a sequence of properties.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="properties">Name/Type pairs for the properties.</param>
    public static ITupleFactory Create(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, Type>> properties)
    {
        // check input
        if (properties == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(properties));
        var propList = properties.ToList();
        if (propList.Select(p => p.Key).Distinct().Count() != propList.Count)
            throw new ArgumentException("Property names must be distinct.");

        lock (_module) // locks access to the static dictionaries
        {
            ITupleFactory result;
            if (_newExpressionFactories.TryGetValue(propList, out result)) // we already have it
                return result;

            var propertyNames = propList.Select(p => p.Key).ToList();
            Type genericTypeDefinition;
            if (!_genericTypeDefinitions.TryGetValue(propertyNames, out genericTypeDefinition))
            {
                #region create new generic type definition
                {
                    var typeBuilder = _module.DefineType($"<>f__AnonymousType{_newExpressionFactories.Count}`{propertyNames.Count}", TypeAttributes.Public | TypeAttributes.AutoClass | TypeAttributes.AnsiClass | TypeAttributes.Sealed | TypeAttributes.BeforeFieldInit);
                    var genParams = propertyNames.Count > 0
                        ? typeBuilder.DefineGenericParameters(propertyNames.Select(p => $"<{p}>j__TPar").ToArray())
                        : new GenericTypeParameterBuilder[0];

                    // attributes on type
                    var debuggerDisplay = "\\{ " + string.Join(", ", propertyNames.Select(n => $"{n} = {{{n}}}")) + " }";
                    // ReSharper disable AssignNullToNotNullAttribute
                    typeBuilder.SetCustomAttribute(new CustomAttributeBuilder(typeof(DebuggerDisplayAttribute).GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(string) }), new object[] { debuggerDisplay }));
                    typeBuilder.SetCustomAttribute(new CustomAttributeBuilder(typeof(CompilerGeneratedAttribute).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes), new object[0]));
                    // ReSharper restore AssignNullToNotNullAttribute

                    var fields = new List<FieldBuilder>();
                    var props = new List<PropertyBuilder>();
                    foreach (var name in propertyNames)
                    {
                        var genParam = genParams[fields.Count];

                        var field = typeBuilder.DefineField($"<{name}>i__Field", genParam, FieldAttributes.Private | FieldAttributes.InitOnly);
                        fields.Add(field);

                        var property = typeBuilder.DefineProperty(name, PropertyAttributes.None, genParam, null);
                        props.Add(property);

                        var getter = typeBuilder.DefineMethod($"get_{name}", MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.HideBySig, genParam, Type.EmptyTypes);
                        var il = getter.GetILGenerator();
                        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
                        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, field);
                        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

                        property.SetGetMethod(getter);
                    }

                    #region ctor
                    {
                        // ReSharper disable once CoVariantArrayConversion
                        var ctorBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public, CallingConventions.Standard, genParams);

                        var il = ctorBuilder.GetILGenerator();

                        // call base class ctor
                        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
                        il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, _objectCtor);

                        // assign args to fields
                        for (var i = 0; i < fields.Count; i++)
                        {
                            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
                            EmitLdarg(il, i + 1);
                            il.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, fields[i]);
                        }

                        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
                    }
                    #endregion

                    #region override Equals
                    {
                        var equals = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("Equals", MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.HideBySig | MethodAttributes.Virtual, typeof(bool), new[] { typeof(object) });
                        typeBuilder.DefineMethodOverride(equals, _objectEquals);

                        var il = equals.GetILGenerator();
                        il.DeclareLocal(typeBuilder);
                        var retFalse = il.DefineLabel();
                        var ret = il.DefineLabel();

                        // local = argument as (the type being constructed)?
                        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
                        il.Emit(OpCodes.Isinst, typeBuilder);
                        il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0);

                        // push result of the "as" operator
                        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);

                        foreach (var field in fields)
                        {
                            var comparer = typeof(EqualityComparer<>).MakeGenericType(field.FieldType);
                            var defaultGetter = TypeBuilder.GetMethod(comparer, _equalityComparerDefaultGetter);
                            var equalsMethod = TypeBuilder.GetMethod(comparer, _equalityComparerEquals);

                            // check if the result of the previous check is false
                            il.Emit(OpCodes.Brfalse, retFalse);

                            // push EqualityComparer<FieldType>.Default.Equals(this.field, other.field)
                            il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, defaultGetter);
                            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
                            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, field);
                            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
                            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, field);
                            il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, equalsMethod);
                        }

                        // jump to the end with what was the last result
                        il.Emit(OpCodes.Br_S, ret);

                        // push false
                        il.MarkLabel(retFalse);
                        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_0);

                        il.MarkLabel(ret);
                        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
                    }
                    #endregion

                    #region override GetHashCode
                    {
                        var getHashCode = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("GetHashCode", MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.HideBySig | MethodAttributes.Virtual, typeof(int), Type.EmptyTypes);
                        typeBuilder.DefineMethodOverride(getHashCode, _objectGetHashCode);

                        var il = getHashCode.GetILGenerator();

                        // init result with seed
                        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, HashCode.Seed);

                        foreach (var field in fields)
                        {
                            var comparer = typeof(EqualityComparer<>).MakeGenericType(field.FieldType);
                            var defaultGetter = TypeBuilder.GetMethod(comparer, _equalityComparerDefaultGetter);
                            var getHashCodeMethod = TypeBuilder.GetMethod(comparer, _equalityComparerGetHashCode);

                            // hash so far * factor
                            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, HashCode.Factor);
                            il.Emit(OpCodes.Mul);

                            // ... + EqualityComparer<FieldType>.GetHashCode(field)
                            il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, defaultGetter);
                            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
                            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, field);
                            il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, getHashCodeMethod);
                            il.Emit(OpCodes.Add);
                        }
                        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
                    }
                    #endregion

                    #region override ToString
                    {
                        var toString = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("ToString", MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.HideBySig | MethodAttributes.Virtual, typeof(string), Type.EmptyTypes);
                        typeBuilder.DefineMethodOverride(toString, _objectToString);

                        var template = "{{ " + string.Join(", ", propertyNames.Select((n, i) => $"{n} = {{{i}}}")) + " }}";

                        var il = toString.GetILGenerator();

                        // push template
                        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, template);

                        // push new array
                        EmitLdc(il, fields.Count);
                        il.Emit(OpCodes.Newarr, typeof(object));

                        var index = 0;
                        foreach (var field in fields)
                        {
                            il.Emit(OpCodes.Dup); // duplicate array ref
                            EmitLdc(il, index); // push array index

                            // store boxed field in array
                            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
                            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, field);
                            il.Emit(OpCodes.Box, field.FieldType);
                            il.Emit(OpCodes.Stelem, typeof(object));

                            index++;
                        }

                        il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, _stringFormat);
                        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
                    }
                    #endregion

                    genericTypeDefinition = typeBuilder.CreateType();
                }
                #endregion

                _genericTypeDefinitions.Add(propertyNames, genericTypeDefinition);
            }

            var type = propList.Count == 0 ? genericTypeDefinition : genericTypeDefinition.MakeGenericType(propList.Select(p => p.Value).ToArray());
            result = new TupleFactoryImpl(type, propertyNames);
            _newExpressionFactories.Add(propList, result);
            return result;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a <see cref="NewExpression"/> for a tuple type with the specified properties.
    /// </summary>
    public static NewExpression MakeNewExpression(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, Expression>> properties)
    {
        var props = properties.ToList();
        var tupleFactory = Create(props.Select(p => new KeyValuePair<string, Type>(p.Key, p.Value.Type)));
        return tupleFactory.MakeNewExpression(props.Select(p => p.Value));
    }

    private sealed class TupleFactoryImpl : ITupleFactory
    {
        public Type TupleType { get; }
        private readonly ConstructorInfo _ctor;
        private readonly MemberInfo[] _properties;

        public TupleFactoryImpl(Type tupleType, IEnumerable<string> propertyNames)
        {
            TupleType = tupleType;

            _ctor = tupleType.GetConstructors().Single();
            var propsByName = tupleType.GetProperties().ToDictionary(p => p.Name);
            _properties = propertyNames.Select(name => (MemberInfo)propsByName[name]).ToArray();
        }

        public NewExpression MakeNewExpression(IEnumerable<Expression> arguments)
        {
            return Expression.New(_ctor, arguments, _properties);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Helper function to pick the optimal op code.
    /// </summary>
    private static void EmitLdarg(ILGenerator il, int index)
    {
        if (index < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        switch (index)
        {
            case 0: il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0); break;
            case 1: il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1); break;
            case 2: il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_2); break;
            case 3: il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_3); break;
            default:
                if (index <= byte.MaxValue)
                    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_S, (byte)index);
                else if (index <= short.MaxValue)
                    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg, (short)index);
                else
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
                break;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Helper function to pick the optimal op code.
    /// </summary>
    private static void EmitLdc(ILGenerator il, int i)
    {
        switch (i)
        {
            case -1: il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_M1); break;
            case 0: il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_0); break;
            case 1: il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_1); break;
            case 2: il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_2); break;
            case 3: il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_3); break;
            case 4: il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_4); break;
            case 5: il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_5); break;
            case 6: il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_6); break;
            case 7: il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_7); break;
            case 8: il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_8); break;
            default:
                if (i >= byte.MinValue && i <= byte.MaxValue)
                    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_S, (byte)i);
                else
                    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, i);
                break;
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Compute a hash code.
/// </summary>
public struct HashCode
{
    // magic numbers for hash code
    public const int Seed = 0x20e699b;
    public const int Factor = unchecked((int)0xa5555529);

    private readonly int? _value;

    private HashCode(int value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Convert to the actual hash code based on what was added so far.
    /// </summary>
    public static implicit operator int(HashCode hc) => hc._value ?? 0;

    /// <summary>
    /// Add a hash code to the state.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>An updated <see cref="HashCode"/>.</returns>
    public static HashCode operator +(HashCode hc, int other) => new HashCode(unchecked((hc._value == null ? Seed : hc._value.Value * Factor) + other));

    /// <summary>
    /// Add a sequence of hash code to the state.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>An updated <see cref="HashCode"/>.</returns>
    public static HashCode operator +(HashCode hc, IEnumerable<int> others) => others.Aggregate(hc, (a, c) => a + c);
}

/// <summary>
/// <see cref="IEqualityComparer{T}"/> for <see cref="KeyValuePair{TKey, TValue}"/>.
/// </summary>
public sealed class KeyValueComparer<TKey, TValue> : IEqualityComparer<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the singleton.
    /// </summary>
    public static KeyValueComparer<TKey, TValue> Default { get; } = new KeyValueComparer<TKey, TValue>();

    private readonly IEqualityComparer<TKey> _keyComparer;
    private readonly IEqualityComparer<TValue> _valueComparer;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initialize by specifying <see cref="IEqualityComparer{T}"/>s for key and value.
    /// </summary>
    public KeyValueComparer(IEqualityComparer<TKey> keyComparer = null, IEqualityComparer<TValue> valueComparer = null)
    {
        _keyComparer = keyComparer ?? EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default;
        _valueComparer = valueComparer ?? EqualityComparer<TValue>.Default;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Equality.
    /// </summary>
    public bool Equals(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> x, KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> y) => _keyComparer.Equals(x.Key, y.Key) && _valueComparer.Equals(x.Value, y.Value);

    /// <summary>
    /// Hash code.
    /// </summary>
    public int GetHashCode(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> obj) => new HashCode() + _keyComparer.GetHashCode(obj.Key) + _valueComparer.GetHashCode(obj.Value);
}

/// <summary>
/// <see cref="IEqualityComparer{T}"/> for a collection.
/// </summary>
public sealed class CollectionComparer<TElement> : IEqualityComparer<ICollection<TElement>>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets an instance using <see cref="EqualityComparer{T}.Default"/> as the element comparer.
    /// </summary>
    public static CollectionComparer<TElement> Default { get; } = new CollectionComparer<TElement>();

    private readonly IEqualityComparer<TElement> _elementComparer;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initialize with a specific element comparer.
    /// </summary>
    public CollectionComparer(IEqualityComparer<TElement> elementComparer = null)
    {
        _elementComparer = elementComparer ?? EqualityComparer<TElement>.Default;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether the specified objects are equal.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// true if the specified objects are equal; otherwise, false.
    /// </returns>
    public bool Equals(ICollection<TElement> x, ICollection<TElement> y)
    {
        if (x == null) return y == null;
        if (y == null) return false;
        return x.Count == y.Count && x.SequenceEqual(y, _elementComparer);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a hash code for the specified object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// A hash code for the specified object.
    /// </returns>
    /// <param name="obj">The <see cref="T:System.Object"/> for which a hash code is to be returned.</param>
    public int GetHashCode(ICollection<TElement> obj)
    {
        var result = new HashCode() + typeof(TElement).GetHashCode();
        if (obj == null) return result;
        result += obj.Count;
        result += obj.Select(element => _elementComparer.GetHashCode(element));
        return result;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
void DoWork(Type type)
{
    var props = type.GetProperties().Where(p => p.HasAttribute(MyAttribute)).ToList();
    var tupleFactory = TupleFactory.Create(props.Select(p => new KeyValuePair<string, Type>(p.Name, p.PropertyType)));
    var param = Expression.Parameter(type, "x");
    var newEx = tupleFactory.MakeNewExpression(props.Select(p => Expression.Property(param, p)));
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda(newEx, param); // <-- type is LambdaExpression, not dynamic
    MyFunction(lambda);
}
```