# Combining multiple expressions to dynamically create select expression containing expressions as getters

Tags: c#, dynamic, .net-4.5, expression-trees, linq-expressions

Given an input of two expressions, e.g.:

```
Expression<Func<Customer,string>> nameExpression = x=>x.Name;
Expression<Func<Customer,string>> nameExpression = x=>x.MarketSegment.Name;
```

and a

```
IQueryable<Customer> query = ..//fetch from dbContext;
```

I want to dynamically create an expression that selects these properties from the query.

the end result would have to execute as follows:

```
Expression<IQueryable<Customer>,IQueryable<dynamic>> query = query.Select(x=>new{
  x=>x.Name,
  x=>x.MarketSegment.Name
});
```

I figured out that Expression.New could be an option in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606104/how-to-create-linq-expression-tree-to-select-an-anonymous-type), but I'm unable to figure out how to pass expressions to it.

Comment: maybe this helps: [Combine several similar SELECT-expressions into a single expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6180704/combine-several-similar-select-expressions-into-a-single-expression)

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get it working using an expression visitor to bind x from the query select to the x parameter in the body of the expressions passed as an input.  I'll try to post an in-depth answer with some code samples later on, when we cleaned it all up.

Comment: Hey @MichielCornille, can you post your code samples please? Thanks!

Comment: It was 2 years ago, I no longer work at the closed-source company I wrote this for. Sorry!